# Using django-fsm to determine the state of an object

Tags: django, state-machine, django-fsm

How do I get the current state of a database item using django-fsm.
I have tried `get_state()` but it returns a null value.

Here is my code:

```
from django.db import models
from django_fsm import FSMField, transition

STATES = ("Open", "In Progress", "Re Opened", "Done", "Closed")
STATES = list(zip(STATES, STATES))

class Ticket(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    state = FSMField(default=STATES[0], choices=STATES)
```

Is there a way of getting the state field using django-fsm library.
Also, how do I get the available state transitions using the model methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the value of the stat field by accessing it like a normal field:

```
ticket.state
```

If you want to get the display friendly version, `FSMField` works like any `CharField(choices=[])` field using:

```
ticket.get_state_display()
```

You can get all of the available transitions by calling:

```
ticket.get_available_state_transitions()
```

You didn't define any transitions on your model so this call would not return anything at the moment.